# Trying to one hot encode data with pd.get_dummies returning only a 0 and 1

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to one hot encode some names of Xpaths in a pandas dataframe by using:

```
one_hot_encoded = pd.get_dummies(test_data['Name'])
```

The original table has 8 general names like :
Button, Text, Select, Dropdown etc.
There are about 500 elements in the table

When I run this line of code it just returns:

```
0
1
```

Am I using this method incorrectly? I thought it could turn a table like

```
0    Cat
1    Dog
2    Dog
3    Snake
```

into

```
     Cat    Dog    Snake
0     1      0       0
1     0      1       0
2     0      1       0
3     0      0       1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method should work.  See this example:

```
s = pd.Series(['Cat', 'Dog', 'Dog', 'Snake'])
pd.get_dummies(s)
```

Output:

```
   Cat  Dog  Snake
0    1    0      0
1    0    1      0
2    0    1      0
3    0    0      1
```

Or you can use the string accessor and string method:

```
s.str.get_dummies()
```